# Checkout code from cvs branch

Tags: cvs

Whild checkout code from cvs branch I am getting like

```
cvs checkout -P -N -r RELEASE1 Stores 
cvs checkout: warning: cannot open /cvs/CVSROOT/val-tags read/write: Permission denied
```

I have used below command.

```
<cvs cvsRoot="${pathofcvs}" package="${cvs.pkg.stores}" command="checkout ${module} ServerTools -r RELEASE1" dest="${basedirstores}/src" failonerror="yes" />
```

Could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: Looks like a problem on the server to me. Talk to your cvs administrator.